# Characters are overlapping when working with document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I was using Word 2010 to create a DOCX document. Before Christmas, Office 2016 was installed on my PC but I'm still using Word 2010 to edit the document.

After working 10 to 20 minutes on the document, characters start to overlap as in the screenshot below. Not all text is affected but ~80%. How can I get Word back to "normal" so that I can work regularly with that document?

I can save the document, close Word and re-open the document to continue editing for another 10 to 20 minutes until the issue happens again.

[image: Screenshot]

This happens in print layout. When I switch to Web layout, things seem to be normal. The compatibility options for the document are set to "Microsoft Word 2010". From the layout options, no checkmarks are checked.

I noticed that Word seems to mix up the font at some point in time. While it is Arial in the beginning, it changes to MyriadPro when it becomes broken.

[image: Arial vs. MyriadPro]

So far I have not found exact steps to reproduce this issue, so I can't tell whether it happens when I edit text, add cells to a table or something else.

I have tried:

- disabling hardware acceleration
- repairing Word

Comment: Surely there is no setting for that. As this happens on a new install of Word, I'd try first re-installing it. Also you can try selecting a word with this overlapping and having a closer look on paragraph and font settings.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I think where Máté Juhász was going was that this is some kind of corruption.  It isn't something you can fix by changing a setting.  It will take reinstalling Word (or at least running the repair utility).  It's possible that the problem is corruption in the document, itself, which would be more likely if that's the only document exhibiting the behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure Word is designed to have two different versions on one pc:(

Comment: @ThomasWeller, if the issue is with Word and not the document, my recollection is that there's a repair utility built into the Uninstall.  There might also be something on the Microsoft web site.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I have tried reinstalling and disabling hardware acceleration. I noticed that the font changes when it gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

We just had this happen this morning. It was the weirdest thing, no font or style settings affected it and its just as you described.

The issue resolved itself for us by going to the print menu and selecting a different printer (we had two). Upon selecting a different printer the print preview (and document in the background) fixed itself.

We were using standard fonts (not as you describe) with Word 2010.

Weirdest thing I've seen in a long time now.